# How to validate my query incase if a field length is 8 then add '+973'

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently i have some fields in my database that are 8 numbers long. I want to add validation in my query
so that if a number is 3888991 then i should add +973 in the beginning using a CASE

```
select * 
from contact 
where length(mobile) = 8

Original                '38881991'
After adding validation '+97338881991'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this string: **3888991** is **only 7** characters long.

With this query you will select all the values from your column that are 8 charcters long. If this is true you will add '+973' on them. But this is select. If you want update statement please do comment.(In this example column name is called number_phone and table is called test).

Use `||` to concate two strings like in the example.

```
select case when length(number_phone) = 8 then '+973' || number_phone
            else number_phone
       end
from test;
```

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=19bec80b60255526ca6746edbd5af172)

You can also use a `DECODE`:

```
select decode(length(number_phone), 8, '+973' || number_phone,number_phone ) 
from test;
```

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=01121807a024e4a5a0cd15811fea53d2)

And if you are going to select only the numbers that are 8 characters long and you do not want to se the ones that are not then:

```
SELECT '+973' || number_phone as number_phone
FROM TEST 
WHERE LENGTH(number_phone) = 8;
```

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=be8f70be5ceb1e132feaa7fd855fad82)

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement:

```
SELECT (CASE 
          WHEN LENGTH(MOBILE) = 8 THEN CONCAT('+973', MOBILE) 
          ELSE MOBILE 
        END) AS MOBILE 
FROM CONTACT 
WHERE LENGTH(MOBILE) = 8;
```

Use `CASE` to validated the mobile number and use `CONCAT` to attach a string the MOBILE.

Here is much cleaner way to do this

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=11f0abea2aeb86ad2aacd99459d847d1)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `BETWEEN` keyword instead of `LENGTH` so that the `index` on the `MOBILE` column is used if there is any. For the concatanation, use `CASE` and `||` (concatanation operator)

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN MOBILE BETWEEN 10000000 AND 99999999 THEN '+973' || MOBILE
        ELSE MOBILE
    END
FROM
    CONTACT
```

Cheers!!